# MySQL InnoDB simple SELECT query takes 0.2 seconds

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have some table:

```
mysql> show columns from room_lesson;
+-------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                   | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                      | int          | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
  ...
  <skipped>
  ...
| online_users_count      | int          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

and simple SELECT query:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM room_lesson WHERE online_users_count = 2;
```

which takes 0.2 seconds to execute.

room_lesson table size is 1.3 Gb.

How can I speed up this query?

Comment: Add an index to `online_users_count`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this query:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM room_lesson WHERE online_users_count = 2;
```

The optimal index is on:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_room_lesson_online_users_count on room_lesson(online_users_count)
```

However, how much the index speeds up the query depends on how often the count is `2` and how wide the rows are in your table.  There should be an improvement, but it might not be dramatic (say, 50% rather than 99%).